# Why does position absolute give anchor tag 100% height of it's container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have been studying bootstrap carousel from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

The left and right side angle bracket controls having classes `carousel-control` are anchor tags. These anchor tags have 100% height of their container. These are also absolutely positioned with respect the container div. My question is:

- Why does position absolute give anchor tag(an inline element) 100% height of it's container?

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute *blockifies* elements but it won't make them 100% height of the parent unless explicity stated.

In this case it's stated in the CSS

```
.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Basically

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Is essentially that same as `height:100%`.

Comment: I am surprised by the fact `top: 0;
bottom: 0;` is equivalent to `height: 100%` when `height` is not defined, auto or 100%. I thought `top` overrides `bottom`. And [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) suggest what you said.

Comment: Height doesn't need to be defined. The top / bottom properties refer to margin offsets. So basically the top margin of the child will be 0px from the top of the parent and the bottom margin 0px from the bottom. That *equates* to `height:100%`. Handy, right?

Comment: Could you provide reference for the fact that `position: absolute` make the element `block` level?

Comment: It's not *exactly* block level...it's **sort of** block level. The display property is *computed* to `block`.

Comment: Yes `getComputedStyle($(".left.carousel-control")[0]).getPropertyValue("display")` returned `block`. But isn't it exactly block level if it has computed style `display: block`?

Comment: No...It's not block level just because it's computed value is display block. It's a little more complex than that....because it's positioned.